# SwiftUI Localization - how to make the UI component and its function the base for localization

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, localization, internationalization

I followed the recommended way on how to localize an iOS app—I use Base localization with English set as the development language.

So I have a structure like this:

```
Localizable.strings
|___ Localizable.strings (English)
|___ Localizable.strings (German)
...
```

and now when I use something like `Text("Cancel")` I will get the following in the `Localizable.strings (German)`:

```
/* No comment provided by engineer. */
"Cancel" = "Abbrechen";
```

Then I looked at the localization files that Facebook uses in their bundle (`Facebook Login` library) and they look like this:

```
"ErrorRecovery.Cancel" = "Abbrechen";
```

Any idea how can I achieve that without getting `ErrorRecovery.Cancel` rendered when the user switches the app language to `English` (which is the development language)?

This would be more desirable for me, because the base itself could be used as an ID across different platform (e.g. if I wanted to also localized my Android app). Also, sometimes the same word in one language doesn't always translate to the same word in another language e.g. `Search` could have the meanings: `to search` and `the search engine` or the `the process of searching`, which in German could be translated to `Suchen` for the former and `Suche` for the latter. In that case `Text("Search")` wouldn't be sufficient to cover those cases. I know that I could use `NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "verb")` and `NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "the process of searching")`, but then the ID of a localization entry would be composed of the `string` and `comment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it is quite easy. All I had to do is provide the optional argument `value` in the `NSLocalizedString.init`.

The `NSLocalizedString` function has the following signature

```
/// - parameter key: An identifying value used to reference a localized string.
///   Don't use the empty string as a key. Values keyed by the empty string will
///   not be localized.
...
/// - parameter value: A user-visible string to return when the localized string
///   for `key` cannot be found in the table. If `value` is the empty string,
///   `key` would be returned instead.

NSLocalizedString(_ key: String, tableName: String? = nil, bundle: Bundle = Bundle.main, value: String = "", comment: String)
```

If the `value` argument is not provided the translation entry after exporting for localization looks as follows:

File.swift

```
NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "Cancel button")
```

en.xliff

```
<trans-unit id="Cancel" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>Cancel</source>
    <target>Cancel</target>
    <note>Cancel button</note>
</trans-unit>
```

However, if the `value` argument is provided, the resulting translation entry looks as follows:

File.swift

```
NSLocalizedString("Navigation.Button.Cancel", value: "Cancel", comment: "Cancel button")
```

en.xliff

```
<trans-unit id="Navigation.Button.Cancel" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>Cancel</source>
    <target>Cancel</target>
    <note>Cancel button</note>
</trans-unit>
```